# jQuery on click event is lost after DOM updated by ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have something working, but as I'm not a so used to code in JS, I don't know if it's the right way to do it.

I have a simple:

```
<div class="offers"></div>
```

And by calling `myUrl`, I retrieve ready to use HTML (some `.offer` div) that I then `append` to the `.offers` div.
But I want to have a click event on these freshly appended `.offer`

```
$.ajax({
    'url': myUrl,
    success: function(data){
        offers.append(data);
        $('.offer').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.offers .offer').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });
    }
});
```

Thank you for your expertise !

Comment: Seems fine, just note that you're attaching an event handler to all `.offer` elements in the DOM, not just the ones you just appended.

Comment: It seems like you're looking for event delegation - see [Understanding jQuery Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: You can use jquery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding events to `.offer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply try that:

```
$(document).on('click', '.offers .offer', function(e) {
    // Code here
});
```

Ideally, for performance purpose, replace **document** by the nearest ID on your DOM.

**UPDATE**: After a comment from  A. Wolff, I removed the "document.ready" not needed here. (please read comment).

Comment: Here looks like it would handle it just fine: `$('.offers').on('click', '.offer', function(e) {...});`. And just as a side note, binding event to document level, you don't need to wrap it in document ready one because the document is already and always be there

Answer (score 1):

Put the event handler outside the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    'url': myUrl
}).done(function(data){
    var offers = $('.offers');
    offers.append(data);
});
$('.offers').on('click','.offer' function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.offers').find('.offer').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```